# Sending FB requests dialog in Windows Phone 7 application?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am working on WP7 project and I need to send request on FB to invite other users to my application, but I am not sure if it's even possible.

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ there is some ui-dialog but it's the only way?

Maybe some1 is more familiar with

> facebook-csharp-sdk

Comment: Do you have a dedicated FB app to go with it?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, the FB dialog isn't available on WP yet. In my case, I use `WebBrowser` and set it uri as this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/). The main api is `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?`. An extra parameters you should pass is : `access_token` (FB token). Hope this help.